# Dynamic array issues VBScript

Tags: arrays, logging, dynamic, vbscript, dynamic-programming

I am reading a txt file line by line, and searching for keywords. As I find a keyword, I am placing it in an array for later use. However I keep coming across problems with my dynamic array. Even if the txt file does not contain keywords, my array shows a couple of empty spaces and fills it up with empty strings. Am I filling up my dynamic array incorrectly? Here is a porting of my code:

```
Dim fso, inputFile, outputFile, notFound(), PortTransferError()
Const outPut = "out.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set input = fso.OpenTextFile("file.txt")
Set outputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(outPut)

i = 0
Do Until input.AtEndOfStream
    line = input.Readline
    Redim Preserve notFound(i)
    Redim Preserve PortTransferError(i)
    If InStr(line, "Couldn't Find:") Then
        notFoundError(i) = line
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf InStr(line, "Cannot Transfer to Port: ") Then
        PortTransferErrorr(i) = line  
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop


input.Close

For each item in notFound
    outputFile.Write(item) 'empty string vals in array
Next 


For each item in PortTransferErrorr
    outputFile.Write(item)
Next
```

Comment: What code do you have currently?

Comment: updated question with curr code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **ReDim** (and copy) the arrays for each input line and you **grow** both arrays for each of the conditions met; so move the ReDim lines to the appropriate Then parts.

Comment: *Translation*: Move the `ReDim` statements inside the relevant part of the `If` statement.